# conformal mapping and its residue

Tags: cv.complex-variables, conformal-geometry

Let $T$ be a closed rectifiable Jordan curve in $\mathbb{C},$ $G$ be the interior of $T,$ and $\Phi$ be a conformal map of $G$ onto the unit disk $\mathbb{D}.$

My question is the following: for $n\in \mathbb{N},$ $a\in \mathbb{D},$ and $w\in G\setminus \{\Phi^{-1}(a)\},$  find  the residue of
$$ \frac{1}{(\Phi(z)-a)^n(\Phi'(z))^{1/2}(z-w)}$$
at $\Phi^{-1}(a).$

Definitely, we can apply the limit formula for higher order poles:
$$\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\rightarrow \Phi^{-1}(a)} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\frac{(z-\Phi^{-1}(a))^n}{(\Phi(z)-a)^n(\Phi'(z))^{1/2}(z-w)}.$$ However, finding the above limit is quite messy (I use, for example, Leibniz’s formula). I would like to know if there's any technique in complex analysis or conformal mapping theory that can help to solve this question easily.

Thank you very much.